# Tried to get value from javascript and get error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have tried to get value from file.js and got error:

**file.js**: this is how i send it:

```
$.post("site.php",{
whatever: ec
});
```

**site.php**: And this is how I tried to get that value:

```
<button onclick="justdoit();">Click my</button>

<script>
function justdoit() {
var whatever = "<?php echo $_POST['whatever']?>";
alert(whatever);
}
</script>
```

Got error in console: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token** on site.php

Comment: PHP is compiled server side, why are you trying to run JavaScript to print PHP code?

Comment: then how i could get value that i send in other way? because i need to get that value to varriable

Comment: [That isn't how AJAX works.](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: I know only how to get it in php **$whatever = $_POST['whatever'];** but i need it in javascript

Comment: How does the rendered output from the PHP file look? Inspect this to get a hint about why there is a JavaScript error.

Comment: you should use ajaxto pass the value to PHP and use the value you want return to the ajax

Comment: before sending in file.js i have put alert(ec); and it's a alerts correct value that should by sended to site.php

Comment: I fixed my problem ;d I was a fool, why do I need to get value from other page using codes :D if everything general on javascript  XDDDDDDDD What is the difference if I use my javascript from .js page or use <script></script>

Answer (score 0):

**Edit2:** (on comment)

If you have everything in your one page, you never need `$.post` to go to server 
and get back it at from same requesting page. However if you need some server processing and need to fetch the processed data from server then use `$.post` i.e. ajax request like i answered in edit1

**Edit1: (on comment)Changed answer**

your site.php (a file just for server side processing) should contain just

```
 $someparam = echo $_POST['whatever'];
```

Now you should know about [$.post](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post#example-5)

your client side file index.php (a file which you are opening in browser and which shows you your page) should contain following

```
<button onclick="justdoit();">Click my</button>
<script>
function justdoit()
{
   $.post("site.php",{whatever: 'Hi I am a string'; }).done(function(data){
       alert(data);
   });
}
</script>
```

**Previous answer**

site.php

```
<?php
$someparam = echo $_POST['whatever'];
?>
//off-course above code should not have any error
```

If it still gives youy problem then there could be somewhere else => In that code which you have not shared. If it works on removing this code. Then you should edit your question and tell the single line which gives error

Comment: it can't be defined because it's only appears on button click and until button click my data doesn't exist because It hasn't been sent yet

Comment: **$_POST['whatever'];** can't be defined because it's only appears on button click and until button click my data doesn't exist because It hasn't been sent yet

Comment: So you have answered your question.. Now i can solve your problem.. You should be ready to explore more things.. i.e. server client communication. You must be knowing that php runs at server (apache software) and html/script run on client(browser)

Comment: I fixed my problem ;d I was a fool, why do I need to get value from other page using codes :D if everything general on javascript  XDDDDDDDD What is the difference if I use my javascript from .js page or use <script></script>

Comment: Glad you solved it and more happy that your concept got better. Still better to read my last edit, you might need some data to be processed by server in future. You can get response at same page with ajax. For a developer it (clinet/server communication) is one of most important and basic concepts

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<button onclick="justdoit();">Click my</button>

<script>
function justdoit() {
var prize = "<?php echo $_POST['prize'];?>";
alert(prize);
}
</script>
```

u forgot  token behind php :P   ';'

Comment: what same this code no return error, mayby before this code is error.

Comment: <?php
$tmp = 'try';

?>



<script>
function justdoit() {
var whatever = "<?php echo $tmp;?>";
alert(whatever);
}
</script>


<button onclick="justdoit();">Click my</button>

Comment: it did work when do u don't send data with method POST.

Comment: it sends but later then i click button in site.php not on page load

Comment: And that code did work. Also I tried change **$tmp** to **$tmp = $_POST['prize'];** and got error that prize undefined but i should get it later after button click not on page load

Comment: OK so i give you solution on your problem but u mast convert it to your code.. <form action='' method='post'>

<input type='submit' value='it work' name='submit'>
</form>


<script>
function justdoit() {
var whatever = "<?php echo $_POST['submit'];?>";
alert(whatever);
}
</script>


<button onclick="justdoit();">Click my</button>

Comment: why do i need this code if your first code given in comments works perfect? it's just a problem that my value will by sent later on button click not on page load so that's why my **$tmp = $_POST['prize'];** undefined

Comment: somehow I need to define it on button click not on page load, any ideas?

Comment: method post inside need declare if(isset($_POST['prize'])){
$rp = $_POST['prize'];} this is only notice but i prefer this method.

Comment: then I get same error **Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token** because php can't define it :/

Comment: im sure you don't need other side of code because i can send it like this **$.post("/manopuslapis/puslapiai/slots.php",{prize: 'Hi I am a string'});** and by sure that I sent it succesfully also I'am getting message in console **XHR finished loading: POST**

Comment: I fixed my problem ;d I was a fool, why do I need to get value from other page using codes :D if everything general on javascript  XDDDDDDDD What is the difference if I use my javascript from .js page or use <script></script>